# Single Constructor Algebraic Data Type: what does it mean?

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

If I make an algebraic data type like this:

```
data Foo = String
```

what is it? It appears to not be a sum type (there's nothing next to it to choose from), but also not a product type (there's no argument to combine it with). Is there some default implied here, like "an ADT with a single constructor is a Sum type"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your type `Foo` is equivalent to the unit type `()`; it's a type with a single value written `String`, just like `()` is a type with a single value written `()`.

Any ADT is a sum-of-products.  So:

```
data Foo
    = One Integer String
    | Two String Integer
```

declares `Foo` to be (warning: not actually Haskell!) `Integer * String + String * Integer`.

If you have a product of 0 types, that's just the empty product `()` (just like `product []` is 1), so

```
data Bar
    = Three
    | Four String Integer
```

declares `Bar` to be `() + String * Integer`.

And, of course, if you have a sum of 1 type, it's just that type (just like `sum [x]` is `x`:

```
data Baz = Five
```

declares `Baz` to be `()`.

So it is a sum type, but trivially, since it's a sum of only one type; and it's a product type, but again trivially, since it's a product of 0 types.

Comment: Still confused as to how it can be *both* a sum and a product type, but knowing about the implied `()` is helpful.

Comment: It is similar to the way that `foldl (+) 1` (a sum) and `foldl (*) 1` (a product) both produce the same value when they act on the empty list.

Comment: @hoosierEE because `1 = sum [1] = product []`, as the answer says.